# 2d array of strings declaration in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to allocate a 2-d array of strings............By that I mean if `t[][]` is the array
    `{char t[0][0]}`     should store a string, 
   `{ char t[0][1]  }`   should store a string etc........Can we use `{char ***t }` to accomplish this ..If so how should I approach it??                                                                                        Or can we also go about doing it like
   `{  char **t[10]  }`  , where 10 is the maximum length of any string I am going to enter in the array...

Comment: Can we assume you are still trying to get the format proper?

Comment: Please also at least consider using a more advanced data structure for this. Your tag is C, but if you're really using C++, consider `std::string` and `std::vector`, etc. If really C, you can still create your own sparse array data structure that could be much more space-efficient, readable, maintainable and safer than higher-dimensional character arrays.

Comment: @Oren That's a 2D array of `char`s what set up in the answer you linked. The OP asks how to create a 2D array of "strings", that is a 3D array of `chars`.

Comment: @DavidNorris From where did you get the idea that he's using C++? Absolutely **nothing** suggests that.

Comment: A missionary ... ;-) @H2CO3

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes, which is why I said "IF you're using C++" right after acknowledging that "Your tag is C." Read.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

To do this you will have to specify the cardinal of the second dimension and the maximum lenght of the string. Then use the name of the array with `sizeof` and the number of strings you want to allocat for:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

        /*  10 is the lenght of each string and 1 for the '\0'
            10 is the number of strings per each 2D array
            5 is the number of 2D arrays */
    char (*array)[10][10+1] = malloc(5*sizeof(*array));

    // Exemple
    strcpy(array[0][0], "hello, world");
    printf("%s\n", array[0][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/5YAgs2)

Comment: @alk You may check the Edit!

Answer (score 0):

well first of all you said: `By that I mean if t[][] is the array {char t[0][0]} should store a string, { char t[0][1] }` , if t[0][1] would store a string then it's not a 2D array you want but rather a 3D array , in a 2D array it's t[0] that stores the string (because a string is an array , and 2D arrays are arrays of arrays) , having said that I'm going to show you how to Dynamically  allocate memory for a 2D array and you can use the principle to create a 3D one.

```
char **matrix = NULL;
int i ;

matrix = malloc(sizeof(char) * ROWS);

for(i = 0 ; i < COLUMNS ; i++)
      matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

and there you have it , just don't forget to use `free` after you're done with that array

**Edit :**

to free a dynamically allocated 2D array you need to `free` the last thing you malloced first , like this :

```
for(i = 0 ; i < COLUMNS ; i++)
     free(matrix[i]);

 free(matrix);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to allocate an array of pointers to pointers to char, which is:

```
char ***array = (char ***)malloc(sizeof(char**)*ARRAY_X);
```

Then, you have to allocate each single array of pointers to chars:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_X; i++){
    array[i] = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *)*ARRAY_Y);
}
```

Finally you have to allocate strings:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_X; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < ARRAY_Y; j++){
        array[i][j] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*ARRAY_Z);
    }
}
```

`ARRAY_X` and `ARRAY_Y` and `ARRAY_Z` are int indicating the dimension of the 2-d array of strings (which is a 3-d array of chars).

Comment: OP said that `t[0][0]` should store a string, not a character.

Comment: **[Do NOT cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).** And better use `sizeof(*p)` instead of `sizeof(type)` for obvious safety reasons.